# Converting String to int using stoi inside a function

Tags: c++, string, int, hashtable, data-conversion

I've tried multiple methods to make the stoi (or other functions) work for my needs (converting a given string to an integer for the purpose of making a key for a hash table). Specifically, I would like to ask why stoi does not like this conversion. I get the error "std::invalid_argument at memory location 0x0034F41C."  I have looked around and couldn't find what I am doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string> 
using namespace std;


enum EntryType { Legitimate, Empty, Deleted }; //creat new data type that holds node status

struct HashNode //create new struct with (hash node)
{
    string element; // item inside node
    enum EntryType info; //status
};

struct HashTable //Creates a new struct (hash table)
{
    int size; //defines size of table
    HashNode *table; //creates pointer to table
};

int HashFun1(std::string skey, int size) //first hash function
{
    std::string key2 = skey;
    int key = stoi(key2);
    return key % size; // will return the inputed value 
}

//int HashFunc2(string key, int size) //second hash function
//{
//  return(key * size - 1) % size; //needs to convert between string and int
//}



int main()
{
    cout<<HashFun1("t", 2);
}
```

Comment: What does skey look like?

Comment: Do you mean the HashFun1 call? cout<<HashFun1("hsdsdsadasdasi", 2);

Comment: `hsdsdsadasdas`? What strange system are you using that considers that as a number?

Comment: cout<<HashFun1("string", 2); Sorry this is better (I was messing around with the amount of chars it was taking in and made a random string). But ya that function takes in a string not an int? Am I doing something wrong here? I updated my code to show everything I've done thus far.

Comment: `stoi`'s job is to transform a string like `"123"` to the int `123`. You're feeding it text that doesn't represent a number, so of course it fails.

Comment: Oh wow, I misunderstood stoi then. Sorry! Does it accept chars like "-" ? Say for an isbn. Nevermind, tried it and it seems to have worked. Thanks for the help!